# how to iterate over the values of my hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I have a hash saved in $target_parser_list

In the debugger this is what I have

```
   DB<3> x  $target_parser_list
0  HASH(0xd570d28)
   'ASCE::ASCE' => undef
   'Bulk::BULK' => undef
   'Bulk::BULKdoi' => undef
   'CQ::Researcher' => undef
   'Highwire::OUP' => undef
   'Highwire::highwire' => undef
   'INFORMIT::INFORMIT' => undef
```

but then when I try to iterate over it

```
foreach my $key(keys %target_parser_list ){
    print $key;
```

}

I get the error that

```
Global symbol "%target_parser_list" requires explicit package name
```

When I try to change it to

```
foreach my $key(keys $target_parser_list ){
```

Then I get an error saying that I need a hash,

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not private variable
```

If I change the $target_parset_list variable to hash

```
my %target_parser_list =  $target_parser_list_conf->getSection('target_parser') || '';
```

Then the output is

```
DB<2> x  %target_parser_list
0  'HASH(0xc758888)'
1  undef
```

and when I print my key it's

```
DB<3> x $key
0  'HASH(0xd5353d0)'
```

Please show me how to iterate over my keys like you see in the beggining.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: Actually $target_parser_list isnt a hash but a reference to a hash so you'd have to: for my $key (sort keys %$target_parser_list) { print $key }

Comment: @Kjetil, that's what I did to solve this, Thanks